# Lock a GPS Puck/Driver to a Specific COM Port

Tags: gps, driver, port

I have 4 vehicles equipped with Globalsat BU-353-S4 GPS pucks attached to Windows 7 laptops with cellular internet access. I am using GOOPS (http://goopstechnologies.com/) to FTP the GPS data streams to our webserver and read them as a Network link in Google Earth. Everything is working as planned, except when the laptop goes into Standby/Sleep mode, the COM port changes. When this happens, GOOPS no longer can read the GPS datastream and we lose live contact with the vehicle.

Does anyone have experience in locking the COM port to a device? I have tried Google searching this but to no avail. I imagine there would be some sort of batch script or program that could insure that the same COM port is always used? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Computer -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Ports -> Right click on (Port associated with GPS module)-> Properties -> Port Settings tab -> Advanced -> Select COM Port Number from drop down.

This should keep it constant every time.